# Disable button not working inside if-else, but working without if-else

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button that should check if user input is not empty before submitting. When user input is set, the button would be disabled, change in innerHTML and have a spinner at the bottom.
Below are what I have got so far.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("form");
let button = document.getElementById("btnSub");
let text = document.getElementById("inpSub");
let spin = document.getElementById("soonSpin");
button.addEventListener("click", submit_fn, false);

function submit_fn() {
  if (text.innerHTML.length == 0) {
    alert("Please fill out the question");
    // return;
  }
  form.submit();
  text.disabled = true;
  button.disabled = true;
  button.innerHTML = " Please wait! Loading...";

  spin.className = "spinner-border";
  spin.setAttribute("role", "status");
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.className = "sr-only";
  span.innerHTML = "Loading...";
  spin.appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="{{url_for('prediction')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input class="border border-danger" id="inpSub" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Enter question here" required />
  <button class="btn-danger" type="submit" id="btnSub">Find closest answer</button>
</form>

<div id="soonSpin"></div>
```

My code always shows the alert in both cases when I have the input or having nothing. And, it doesn't run any of the code outside if statement, but do render to the next page.

Does anyone know what's the problem here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to check `text.value`, not `text.innerHTML`

Comment: omg, it works, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen for the change on the text input as well to disable / enable the button :

```
text.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if (text.value.length > 0) {
    button.disabled = false
  } else {
    button.disabled = true
  }
});
```

Check the comments to see the differences in the code : ( mainly check `text.value` instead of `text.innerHTML` )

```js
let form = document.getElementById("form");
let button = document.getElementById("btnSub");
let text = document.getElementById("inpSub");
let spin = document.getElementById("soonSpin");

button.addEventListener("click", submit_fn, false);
text.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if (text.value.length > 0) {
    button.disabled = false
  } else {
    button.disabled = true
  }
});


function submit_fn(e) {
  if (text.value == 0) {
    alert("Please fill out the question");
    // return;
  }
  
  e.preventDefault(); // comment this to submit the form
  
  // uncomment this line to submit the form
  // form.submit();
  
  text.disabled = true;
  button.innerHTML = " Please wait! Loading...";

  spin.className = "spinner-border";
  spin.setAttribute("role", "status");
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.className = "sr-only";
  span.innerHTML = "Loading...";
  spin.appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="{{url_for('prediction')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input class="border border-danger" id="inpSub" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Enter question here" required />
  <button class="btn-danger" type="submit" disabled id="btnSub">Find closest answer</button>
</form>

<div id="soonSpin"></div>
```